# What is the meaning of the different interface types in Ian Sommervilles's Software Engineering?

Tags: c#, object-oriented-design, interfaces

Reading Ian Sommervilles's Software engineering, he mentiones there are following interfaces:

- **Paramater interface**: data or functions are passed from one component
  to another
- **Shared memory interface**: block of memory is shared between
  components
- **Procedural interface**: interfaces where one component
  encapsulates a set of procedures that can be called by other
  components. Objects and reusable components have this.

I do not understand, is this talking about "interface" types (such as using interface keyword in c#)? What would be example of those? I am a bit confused as this mentioned objects and reusable components, I am not sure what is meant by interface that - public methods?

Comment: "*is this talking about "interface" types*". No. In this context, "interface" refers to how one component of a system talks to another component, ie how they interface to each other.

Comment: Ditto, @DavidArno. Many (many) a program in the good-old-days was fubared beyond understanding by sharing memory. "Interface" implies control and consistency. Sharing memory is the anti-matter of "interface"